# How to install a specific version of NASM on MacOS

Tags: macos, nasm, make-install

I got NASM for MacOS from
http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11.06/macosx/

**How to do I install this specific version of NASM?**

I know that I can do a `brew install nasm`. But I dont want the latest version. I want to install `NASM 2.11.06` for MacOS.

How should I install the `nasm-2.11.06-macosx.zip` that I have downloaded?

**Environment:**
I am running *MacOS Sierra*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you would need to do is:

1. Unpack the zip file
2. Update your `PATH` statement to include the location you unzipped the version you downloaded
3. Open a terminal window
4. Type `nasm -v` to confirm it is found and you have the right version you want

Answer (score 2):

Here's the line I use to get one of the nasm builds installed on macOS:

`curl https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.14.03rc2/macosx/nasm-2.14.03rc2-macosx.zip -o nasm.zip && unzip nasm.zip && rm nasm.zip && mv nasm* nasm && export PATH=~/nasm:$PATH`