# Error showing in Terminal "-bash: name: command not found"

Tags: nasm

[image]the file is unable to assemble in macos terminal

Macbooks-MacBook-Air:Desktop macbook$ cd ~/Desktop
Macbooks-MacBook-Air:Desktop macbook$ nasm -f macho h1.asm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have installed?

[nasm for mac os](https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.14rc16/macosx/)

How to do this: [How to install a specific version of NASM on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746295/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-nasm-on-macos)

After that check it:

```
which nasm
```